# Why is my ball 21°?

Tags: tagpro

New 'degrees' have started displaying underneath balls in [tagpro](http://tagpro-chord.koalabeast.com). What are they?

[image: rekd]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The 'degrees' are basically to show your amount of wins. It increases if you get more wins.
[image: Low degrees]

You can check your current progress to the next degree on your profile page.